# Last promise not fullfilled on first call

Tags: promise, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

Here is some code, in a cloud function, on Parse-Server using promises.
It is supposed to be called once and do a certain job of removing some contents layed out in a tree stucture.

The problem is that I have to call the same code twice to get the job fully done.
If someone can take a look and say what is wrong, that will be very helpful.
Here is what happens, when the code is called for the first time. All the work is done, except the last removal.

That means the code from the line:

```
console.log("We finally remove the unit.");
```

and after is not executed.

When the code is run the second time, the last part is properly executed.

I may have done something incorrect with the promises, but I can't see what.

```
Parse.Cloud.define
("removeTheThing", function(request, response) {
 var thingQuery;
 thingQuery = .....;
 .....

 thingQuery.find().then
 (function(resUnit) {
  var secondLevelQuery;
  secondLevelQuery = .....;
  .....

  secondLevelQuery.find().then
  (function(resSentence) {
   var thirdLevelQuery;
   thirdLevelQuery =  .....;
   .....

   thirdLevelQuery.find().then
   (function(resTranslat) {
    var fourthLevelQuery;
    fourthLevelQuery = .....;
    .....

    fourthLevelQuery.find().then
    (function(resExplain) {
     var destroyPromises = [];
     for (i = 0; i < resExplain.length; i++) {
       destroyPromises.push(resExplain[i].destroy({}));
     }
     return Parse.Promise.when(destroyPromises);
     }).then
    (function() {
      var destroyPromises = [];
      for (iT = 0; iT < resTranslat.length; iT++) {
        destroyPromises.push(resTranslat[iT].destroy({}));
      }
      return Parse.Promise.when(destroyPromises);
    }).then
    (function() {
     var destroyPromises = [];
     const s3 = new aws.S3();
     for (iS = 0; iS < resSentence.length; iS++) {
       // Let us remove the voice recording:
       destroyPromises.push(s3.deleteObject({
         Bucket: "londonspeak",
         Key: resSentence[iS].get("audio")
       }).promise());
       destroyPromises.push(resSentence[iS].destroy({}));
     }
     return Parse.Promise.when(destroyPromises);
    }).then
    (function() {
      console.log("We finally remove the unit.");
      //return resUnit[0].destroy({});
      //return Parse.Promise.when(resUnit[0].destroy({}));//Promise()
      var destroyPromise = [];
      destroyPromise.push(resUnit[0].destroy({}));
      return Parse.Promise.when(destroyPromise);
    }).then(response.success);
   });
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: This isn't to do with promises *per se*. The approach is wrong whether the underlying destruction be asynchronous or synchronous . As written, the code traverses only in order to destroy, not to drill down into the tree structure. Therefore not all of the tree is visited and (a) tree members can be destroyed without all child/grandchild etc elements having been visited and destroyed; (b) on completion, some tree members may still exist. Double trouble!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What you say "As written, the code traverses ...., some tree members may still exist" is true and I was a bit fast when I used the expression "tree structure" (my data structure is in fact simpler than a tree). But in practical terms this part works for my case because everything in "the tree" is destroyed as I wish. The problem is that only the root is left over. It should be destroyed in the last part of the code, before the line "then(response.success)". As I mentioned, I need to make a second call, this is what I do not quite understand.

Comment: Is the initial query different from the queries at other levels?

Comment: I do not see any difference. On the first call, on it depends all subsequent queries and they do their job. On the second call, the final destroy happens based on the initial query.

Comment: I finally figured out the problem. The "s3.deleteObject" line is causing the issue. The sound files were not destroyed as expected. That explains the rest.

Comment: Consider adding `.catch()` handler(s) to log errors and optionally perform error recovery.